# Bootstrap 4 adding space above DIV tag with PHP include

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have found a very frustrating issue! When I use a PHP include for a file that has a DIV tag, a line space is added above. For testing I've stripped out everything as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.4/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    Beep 1!
  </div>
</div>
<?php include('test-include.php'); ?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    Beep 3!
  </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The include file contains the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    Beep 2!
  </div>
</div>
```

If I replace the include line with the contents of the file the three divs output without any spacing. If I use the include command here is a gap between the first and second.

Tried in different browsers and same result.

Am I missing something really obvious/simple?

Thank you!

Comment: Seems to be encoding issue in file editor - save the files in Notepad and is fine.

Comment: My first guess would be that you're on a windows computer and uploading to a Linux/Unix server. Windows ends lines with CR/LF whereas Unix only needs CR for linebreaks. Some editors will make this conversion when uploading to Unix from  windows machine.

Comment: @JasonOlson that difference in line breaks doesn't matter though, in HTML both versions are interpreted the same. Much more likely candidate here would be a BOM at the start of the included file, I think.

Comment: What problem are you facing? Spaces between block-level elements are generally meaningless.